# Copy a string occurring before a particular pattern.

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep, sed, awk

I am to copy this `emuEventTrapInformative` from below.

```
-- Traps
   emuEventTrapInformative TRAP-TYPE
        ENTERPRISE compaq
        VARIABLES  { scellNameDateTime,
                     shelfId,
                     shelfElementType,
                     shelfElementNum,
                     shelfErrorCode }
```

What I want done is that I search for the **first instance of `TRAP-TYPE` in a file** and copy everything before it within the line itself.

`emuEventTrapInformative` will vary from file to file
Using anything sed/grep/awk.

Comment: Rather than asking so many somewhat similar questions (seems intermediate to me), please consider asking a question regarding your final goal so that help you with that....

Comment: So TRAP-TYPE and emuEventTrapInformative are always going to be on the same line or there's gonna be cases where they're split into two lines ?

Comment: They are always going to be on the same line.

Comment: @heemayl My goal is very complicated. I am creating a script to convert a file into another file with a particular format.  I am to convert [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11734891/) to [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11734899/) using a bash script.

Comment: Is there patterns among the lines of the file that can be converted or each stanza is different from the other?

Comment: They do. There are about 260 of these files that need conversion and these files vary in 30 different formats. So i am to make a script considering all factors.

Comment: @SamFlynn so in case the file has another chunk of text starting with TRAP-TYPE, you're not gonna need it, right ? just the first ,top occurence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '/TRAP-TYPE/ {print $1; exit}' foo
```

---

*Note*

This will only work if there is only a single field before `TRAP-TYPE` as in OPs case

---

*Example*

```
$ cat foo
sCSISmart5  TRAP-TYPE
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone
    VARIABLES {cycHostAdapterNumber, cycHostAdapterID, cycManagerID}
    DESCRIPTION
    "The HostAdapter# %d has new HostAdapter Id %s and Manager Id %s"
    --#TYPE "Host Adapter changed"
    --#SUMMARY "The HostAdapter# %d has new HostAdapter Id %s and Manager Id %s"
    --#ARGUMENTS {0,1,2}
    --#SEVERITY CRITICAL
    --#TIMEINDEX 100
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"
    --#HELPTAG 109
::=  109

--This Trap is issued when a Host adapter fails.

sCSISmart6  TRAP-TYPE
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone
    VARIABLES {cycHostAdapterNumber}
    DESCRIPTION
    "The HostAdapter# %d has Failed"
    --#TYPE "Host adapter failed"
    --#SUMMARY "The HostAdapter# %d has Failed"
    --#ARGUMENTS {0}
    --#SEVERITY CRITICAL
    --#TIMEINDEX 100
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"
    --#HELPTAG 110
::=  110

$ awk '/TRAP-TYPE/ {print $1; exit}' foo
sCSISmart5
```

Comment: Okay I just want it to print for the first instance i.e., in your example it will only print `sCSISmart5`. Any Idea how to do that?

Comment: a quick way is `head -1`. Fixed =)

Comment: Nice, +1. Note, however, that this will only work if there is only a single field before `TRAP-TYPE`.

Comment: @terdon In OPs case it is so: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11734891/

Comment: Yes, I just pointed it out for future readers. By the way, you might want to do `awk '/TRAP-TYPE/ {print $1; exit}' file` instead of `head` to avoid having to process the entire file.

Comment: @terdon Thank you :) That's a very good point.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `grep`:

```
$ grep -m 1 TRAP-TYPE file
   emuEventTrapInformative TRAP-TYPE
```

The `-m 1` tells `grep` to exit after the first match. To get only the `emuEventTrapInformative` part, you could just delete `TRAP-TYPE` and any whitespace preceding it:

```
$ grep -m 1 TRAP-TYPE file | sed 's/ *TRAP-TYPE//'
   emuEventTrapInformative
```

Alternatively, you can use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$ grep -Pom 1 '.*(?=TRAP-TYPE)' file 
   emuEventTrapInformative
```

The `-o` tells `grep` to only print the matched portion of the line and the `-P` enables Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which support lookaheads.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `sed` version:

`sed -n 's/TRAP-TYPE//p' inp-file.txt`

For the example you've provided, the output is:

```
sed -n 's/TRAP-TYPE//p' inp-file.txt                                        
emuEventTrapInformative
```

In your original question you've requested first instance of TRAP-TYPE in a file. If you have more than one intance `sed -n 's/TRAP-TYPE//p' | head -n1` will do the trick

Here's another version that extracts *multiple* strings (just in case you need one , ever) , if you have more than one instance of TRAP-TYPE in the file.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS="TRAP-TYPE"} NR>1{ print previous } {previous=$NF}' inp-file.txt                                                     
emuEventTrapInformative
someOtherString
```

**Explanation**:

RS is the record separator. We divide the whole text into records, by using the TRAP-TYPE as string, then print last item before the separator. The problem is that last record ends with curly brace. So to avoid that we use `NR>1{print previous}{previous=$NF}` construct so that we can ignore last line.

**My inp-file.txt**

```
-- Traps
   emuEventTrapInformative TRAP-TYPE
        ENTERPRISE compaq
        VARIABLES  { scellNameDateTime,
                     shelfId,
                     shelfElementType,
                     shelfElementNum,
                     shelfErrorCode }

-- Traps
   someOtherString TRAP-TYPE
        ENTERPRISE compaq
        VARIABLES  { scellNameDateTime,
                     shelfId,
                     shelfElementType,
                     shelfElementNum,
                     shelfErrorCode }
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's a Perl version:

```
< inputfile perl -ne 's/^ +(.*) +TRAP-TYPE/$1/&&print'
```

- `-n`: places a `while (<>) {[...]}` loop around the script
- `-e`: reads the script from the arguments

Perl command breakdown:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the pattern
- `^`: matches the start of the line
- `+`: matches one or more  characters
- `(.*)`: matches and groups any number of any character before one or more  characters
- `TRAP-TYPE`: matches a `TRAP-TYPE` string
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `$1`: replaces with the captured group
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the modifiers